# How do I install Gmic and Resynthesizer plugin for gimp 2.10?

Tags: software-installation, snap, gimp

I installed GIMP 2.10.8 with snap. I can't find the resynthesizer plugin for download for Linux. The gmic zip I got from https://gmic.eu/download has a `gmic_gimp_qt`. I copied it into `snap/gimp/130/.config/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins/` but nothing changed.

How do I install these plugins?

Answer (score 0):

PSA for those who are using linux mint 19 gimp flatpack is buggy and will not recognize plugins.

this worked

Installing:
open a terminal and type:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp

Removing:
open a terminal and type:
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp

then place the gmic_gimp_qt in /home/YOUR USERNAME/.config/gimp/2.10/plugins/